# AWS Cognito - server side Google signin

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am building an auth microservice based on AWS lambdas and Cognito.

I a currently trying to build social sign in with Google. After reviewing instructions, they all point out to either using the Cognito hosted UI or AWS Amplify.
However, my app is a pure backend based on the serverless framework and performs all authentication server side.

Thse are the resources defined within my serverless.yaml:

```
# serverless.yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    UserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: ${self:service}-pool-${sls:stage}
        Schema:
          - Name: email
            Required: true
            Mutable: true
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 6
        EmailConfiguration:
          EmailSendingAccount: COGNITO_DEFAULT
        VerificationMessageTemplate:
          DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_CODE
    
    CognitoUserPoolIdentityProvider:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
      Properties: 
        ProviderName: Google
        AttributeMapping:
          email: Email
        ProviderDetails:
          client_id: ${env:GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
          client_secret: ${env:GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
          authorize_scopes: email name openid
        ProviderType: Google
        UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool

    UserPoolClient:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
      Properties:
        ClientName: ${self:service}-pool-client-${sls:stage}
        GenerateSecret: false
        UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool
        AccessTokenValidity: 5
        IdTokenValidity: 5
        ExplicitAuthFlows:
          - ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH
```

I am able to perform the Google sign in and generate Google's IdToken and AccessToken, I must now however send these tokens over to cognito and exchange them for cognito credentials.

I imagine that this must bear some resemblance to how it is done in a traditional USER/PASSWORD flow:

```
# Simple login (USER/PASS)
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from "aws-lambda";
import {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    AdminInitiateAuthCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";

import { commonCheckInput } from "common";

const cognito = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});

const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
};

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = JSON.parse(event.body!);

        commonCheckInput({ email, password });

        if (password.length < 6) {
            return {
                statusCode: 400,
                body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Invalid password length" }),
                headers
            }
        }

        const userPoolId = process.env.USER_POOL_ID!;
        const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID!;

        const params = {
            AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
            UserPoolId: userPoolId,
            ClientId: clientId,
            AuthParameters: {
                USERNAME: email,
                PASSWORD: password
            }
        };
        const initiateAuthCommand = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand(params);
        const cognitoResponse = await cognito.send(initiateAuthCommand);

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                idToken: cognitoResponse.AuthenticationResult?.IdToken,
                accessToken: cognitoResponse.AuthenticationResult?.AccessToken,
                refreshToken: cognitoResponse.AuthenticationResult?.RefreshToken
            }),
            headers
        };
    } catch (error: any) {
        const message = error.message ? error.message : "Internal server error";
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
            headers
        };
    }
}
```

I just don't understand how to create a Cognito user using the social signup through the SDK and then how to authenticate then.
I was drafting something like this for authentication:

```
# googleLogin
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from "aws-lambda";
import {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    AdminInitiateAuthCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";

import { commonCheckInput } from "common";

const cognito = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});

const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
};

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
        const { googleIdToken } = JSON.parse(event.body!);

        commonCheckInput({ googleIdToken });

        const userPoolId = process.env.USER_POOL_ID!;
        const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID!;

        const params = {
            AuthFlow: "CUSTOM_FLOW",
            UserPoolId: userPoolId,
            ClientId: clientId,
            AuthParameters: {
                "custom:googleIdToken": googleIdToken
            }
        };
        const initiateAuthCommand = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand(params);
        const cognitoResponse = await cognito.send(initiateAuthCommand);

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                idToken: cognitoResponse.AuthenticationResult?.IdToken,
                accessToken: cognitoResponse.AuthenticationResult?.AccessToken,
                refreshToken: cognitoResponse.AuthenticationResult?.RefreshToken
            }),
            headers
        };
    } catch (error: any) {
        const message = error.message ? error.message : "Internal server error";
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
            headers
        };
    }
}
```

But I couldn't find any information regarding these operations in the SDK or Cognito documentations.
Does anyone know how to perform them?